# Cpp what is declaration of char a [10][100]

Tags: c

I have a theoretical question about c++ arrays and strings. What is declaration of char [10][100]? How many strings it may have and what is lenght of array?

Comment: It's a two dimensional array of `char` - not sure what part of that is unclear

Comment: What is wrong with `std::vector<std::string>`?

Comment: What is maximal lenght of srtring in this array 100 or 99?

Comment: @Zeljo Consider learning from a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: "What is maximal lenght of srtring in this array 100 or 99? " - that depends on whether you are counting the trailing `\0` as part of the string or not.

Comment: Normally you don't count \0 as a part of the string, so the length is 99.

Answer (score 0):

it is a two dimensional `character` array

now **assuming** your second dimension as a string [100 characters]

so simply put it will be 10 strings with each max length of 100

Answer (score -1):

The declaration char [10][100] represents a two-dimensional array of characters in C++. It is an array of size 10, where each element is an array of size 100. In other words, it is an array with 10 rows and 100 columns, where each element can hold a single character.